# WFFM 8.0 Update 1 with Analytics Disabled (no MongoDB) Issue

Tags: wffm

I have Web Forms for Marketers 8.0 Update-1 installed on Sitecore Experience Platform 8.0 Update-1 website which has analytics disabled and there is no MongoDB installed.

When submitting any form I got the following error:

```
4972 2017:02:02 03:27:53 WARN Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: owner
Exception: System.ArgumentNullException
Message: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: owner
Source: Sitecore.Kernel
   at Sitecore.Diagnostics.Assert.ArgumentNotNull(Object argument, String argumentName)
   at Sitecore.Diagnostics.Log.Warn(String message, Object owner)
   at Sitecore.WFFM.Core.Extensions.Warn.IsNull(Object obj, String name)
   at Sitecore.WFFM.Analytics.AnalyticsTracker.get_SessionId()
   at Sitecore.Form.Core.FormDataHandler.ExecuteSaveActions(ID formId, ControlResult[] fields, ActionDefinition[] actions)
   at Sitecore.Form.Core.FormDataHandler.ProcessData(ID formID, ControlResult[] fields, ActionDefinition[] actions, CallContext context)
```

The submitted form data will be saved into MongoDB by default, Is there any way I can use to save to SQL instead, I tried the following marketplace module which also needs the analytics to be enabled?!

https://marketplace.sitecore.net/Modules/W/WEB_FORMS_FOR_MARKETERS_8X_SQL_PROVIDER.aspx

Answer (score 2):

After switching to MongoDB, Sitecore introduced an option to use an SQL storage again only in 8.1. So I don't believe staying at 8.0 is an option in your situation.

If your decide to upgrade to 8.1, check out this tutorial on configuring the SQL storage for forms:

https://doc.sitecore.net/web_forms_for_marketers/81/setting_up_web_forms/installing/use_a_custom_sql_provider_to_store_form_data

See the configuration file `Include/Sitecore.WFFM.Dependencies.config` for available forms storage providers.

Comment: Thanks, Dmytro, I know how to configure it in 8.1 but I am wondering if there is any workaround in 8.0 by which I can achieve this, So what you are saying is I only have to upgrade my site to 8.1

Comment: @MohammedSyam That is my understanding, yes.